# Rails Active Storage: Remove a picture and upload a new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using Rails 6.1 and Active Storage and have a model movies that has a poster attached.

Everything works fine but I cannot seem to attach a new poster after I have deleted an old one - I get

```
FrozenError (can't modify frozen attributes)
```

Here is the movie model with the methods in question:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_one_attached :poster
    ...

  # technically this method is defined in application_record.rb as it is needed elsewhere too
  def grab_picture(input, output)
    unless input.nil? || input.empty?
      picture_attach = URI.open(input)
      picture_name = File.basename(picture_attach.path)
      if output.attached?
        output.purge
      end
      output.attach(io: picture_attach, filename: picture_name)
    end
  end
```

On the rails console, I can do something like this (assuming m is a movie object with a poster attached):

```
> m.poster.attached?
=> true
> m.poster.purge
...
> m.poster.attached?
=> false
> m.grab_picture('some_image_url', m.poster)
=> #<ActiveStorage::Attached::Changes::CreateOne:0x00007fd4bd90d488 @attachable={:io=>#<Tempfile:/var/folders/m3/6_527vrn01b1rz0lns767dv80000gn/T/open-uri20220120-2419-8vq9td>, :filename=>"open-uri20220120-2419-8vq9td"}, @record=#<Movie id: 89, title: "The Avengers", runtime: 143, release_year: 2012, sort_title: "Avengers", created_at: "2022-01-19 13:31:00.176136000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-01-20 08:07:34.590191000 +0000", country: "US">, @name="poster", @blob=#<ActiveStorage::Blob id: nil, key: nil, filename: "open-uri20220120-2419-8vq9td", content_type: "image/jpeg", metadata: {"identified"=>true}, service_name: "local", byte_size: 1093283, checksum: "iQ+KdZxaPI1TavdrT4mpDw==", created_at: nil>>
irb(main):016:0> m.grab_picture(m.image_url, m.poster)
  TRANSACTION (1.6ms)  BEGIN
  Movie Update (1.8ms)  UPDATE `movies` SET `movies`.`updated_at` = '2022-01-20 08:08:40.457643' WHERE `movies`.`id` = 89
  TRANSACTION (8.1ms)  COMMIT
  Disk Storage (9.5ms) Uploaded file to key: kryn45dplbsd5i8ag9rjrhd7xk8w (checksum: iQ+KdZxaPI1TavdrT4mpDw==)
  TRANSACTION (2.0ms)  BEGIN
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists? (1.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `active_storage_attachments` WHERE `active_storage_attachments`.`blob_id` IS NULL AND (1=0) LIMIT 1
  TRANSACTION (1.7ms)  COMMIT
  Disk Storage (0.4ms) Deleted file from key: kryn45dplbsd5i8ag9rjrhd7xk8w
  Disk Storage (0.2ms) Deleted files by key prefix: variants/kryn45dplbsd5i8ag9rjrhd7xk8w/
  TRANSACTION (1.3ms)  BEGIN
  Movie Exists? (2.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `movies` WHERE `movies`.`title` = 'The Avengers' AND `movies`.`id` != 89 LIMIT 1
  Movie Update (1.8ms)  UPDATE `movies` SET `movies`.`updated_at` = '2022-01-20 08:08:40.661803' WHERE `movies`.`id` = 89
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists? (1.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `active_storage_attachments` WHERE `active_storage_attachments`.`blob_id` IS NULL AND (1=0) LIMIT 1
  TRANSACTION (1.8ms)  ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from (irb):16:in `<main>'
        3: from app/models/application_record.rb:18:in `grab_picture'
        2: from app/models/movie.rb:72:in `block in <class:Movie>'
        1: from app/models/application_record.rb:16:in `grab_picture'
FrozenError (can't modify frozen attributes)
```

I don't understand this entirely. Which attributes are frozen? What extra step do I need to do in order to fully and completely remove the poster attachment?
Note that attaching a picture to a movie that never had one is no problem?

EDIT: After some testing: I can actually just attach a new poster to an existing movie that already has a poster - "overwrite" the attachment so to speak. But the functionality that I am trying to implement is the possibility to remove a poster (and potentially attach another one at some point after that). That's where I am struggling.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveStorage::Blob#purge` destroys the blob record, freezing its attrubtes.

Try to attach the new picture without purging the previous one. ActiveStorage will do this for you internally.

Comment: that does not work - the attachment method sends rails into an infinite loop, repeating:  Movie Exists? (1.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `movies` WHERE `movies`.`title` = 'The Avengers' AND `movies`.`id` != 99 LIMIT 1

Comment: Could you update your code without the purge to see what could happen?

Comment: OK so I used a new movie object and reattached a poster from a URL without purging anything before. That worked. So that seems to be ok. However, I would like to have a functionality to remove a poster from a movie completely... and then maybe later add one again. That is the functionality that I am still trying to implement... and struggling still. As soon as I purge - stuff doesn't work any longer. I have updated the original question to reflect that.